# Finding the logs in a hacked server.

Tags: linux, security, logs

My server has been hacked and the hacker managed to ssh as root (I know, horrible mistake on my part).

What files should I be looking for to discover the origin of the attack? (At least their IP).

The server is really old, it's running Red Hat 9. There wasn't anything important in it, though.

Comment: Maybe this would be more appropriate in serverfault? Not sure, feel free to move this question.

Comment: which services you had  running? what does auth.log says? What does apache logs say? Also consider that any skilled hacker would empty such traces.

Comment: Apache, MySQL and PHP 5. Where is auth.log located? I'm kinda new :S

Comment: Seems that the file in RedHat is /var/log/audit/audit.log still as I've stated before I beleive any hacker would empty it.

Comment: I'm not home at the moment, are there any other files I should be looking into? Like /var/log/lastlog

Comment: Since it's SSH `wtmp` should have a record for this user's login (including exact time and remote host). I don't have a RH9 box but that's fairly old. You can dump the contents via the `lastlog` command. Since they got root, it's probably best to take that as informational only and try to corroborate it some other way. Any and all information could have been modified by the attacker once they got root.

Comment: It's probably going to just point to a cloud VM, though. In my (albeit limited experience) most attackers set up VM's with legitimate providers and attempt to carry out attacks from there since they know worst case scenario is that the hosting service shuts down the VM and they move on.

Comment: The ip address of the attacker is relativly meaningless as ip addresses do not identify individuals and can easily be spoofed. Better off spending your time learning to secure your servers, including ssh. Personally I advise you disable password authentication and use keys.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into /var/log/auth.log, that normally has the records for ssh logins.

But unless the attacker is really dumb they removed the traces of their access and/or did not come from a retraceable IP.

Comment: This file is not present in RedHat at least not on my install.

Comment: To find out which files in /var/log are written when an ssh login is done. Touch a file `/var/log/tmptouch` and then login using ssh to the machine and do a `ls -lrt /var/log` all the files touched later than `tmptouch` can have information about ssh login, look if they are readable, not all files in /var/log are.

Comment: Redhat systems use /var/log/secure.

Answer (score 1):

First look up how your sshd-logging is set up (normally **sshd_config**).

Then look up where your syslog/rsyslog/syslog-ng or whatever your system uses for logging is configured for that target and where it logs to.

Then look up the information in that log-file.